# Dock Style for control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a user control which contains 2 buttons at the top and a grid below it. Let me name this as UC1

This UC1 is placed inside another user control UC2.

During some cases in UC2, i do not need 2 buttons on UC1 and hence i make those 2 buttons as visible false and set the grid's dock style to Fill.

```
grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

But in some cases, i need those 2 buttons on UC1, I make 2 buttons as visible true followed by settng grid's dock style to None

```
grid.Dock = DockStyle.None;
```

After setting DockStyle to none, the grid's width becomes smaller and doesn't fit the width of UC2.

if i don't use DockStyle.None, then grid and button gets overlapped.

How can i resolve the width of grid in UC1 to fit the width of UC2 ?

Comment: try `grid.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom`

Comment: I tried DockStyle.Bottom and the grid fits to bottom of UC2 control. This leads to huge white space between button and grid. So i cannot go with this solution

Answer (score 0):

You should place a TableLayoutPanel first on CU1, set it to Fill.

Then in this table, create a row for the a panel that holds the two buttons, and a second row to hold CU2. The extra panel and CU2 can then all be set to Fill.

To show or hide the buttons, simply set the row height of the panel's row to a proper value or zero.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesstion but UC1 design should not be touched as it is being used in most of the screens. Any other solution ?